# Retrieve Image from SQL Server & set to PictureBox Image Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, user-controls, picturebox

I want to retrieve image from SQL Server(Database) using Entity Framework and set it to PictureBox Image Property
I have maked a user control & inherit it to PictureBox (Name:DisplayImage)

```
    public static void LoadDisplay(Guid? DisplayID, string Name, byte[] image)
    {
        DisplayImage objDisplayImage = new DisplayImage();
        DisplayList.Add(objDisplayImage);
        objDisplayImage.Name = Name;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
        Image myImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        objDisplayImage.Image = myImage;
        objDisplayImage.DisplayID = DisplayID;
        PlayerForm.Instance.Controls.Add(objDisplayImage);
    }
```

but Image is not loading on PictureBox

Comment: What is the format of the image you're using? (PNG, JPEG, BMP, etc?). If it's BMP note that the in-memory format is different on the on-disk format (for example, it lacks a header).

Comment: Also, please wrap your code in a `try/catch` block to see if there are any uncaught exceptions. What does VS's debugger visualizer report about the Image you're creating?

Comment: there is no exception in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
try
{
    // get image from object
    byte[] _ImageData = new byte[0];
    _ImageData = (byte[])_SqlRetVal;
    System.IO.MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(_ImageData);
    _Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(_MemoryStream);
}
catch (Exception _Exception)
{
    // Error occurred while trying to create image
    // send error message to console (change below line to customize error handling)
    Console.WriteLine(_Exception.Message);

    return null;
}
```